# AWS SSM DOcument Assume Role is unable to be assumed for Service Catalog

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-ssm, assume-role, aws-service-catalog

I am using Service Catalog to execute the SSM Automation Document, so my Service Catalog has its own Role called "My_END_USER_Role", and I've created another role with permission to stop the EC2 for SSM Automation Document.

**My_END_USER_Role** this roles has the **AWSServiceCatalogEndUserFullAccess**, the easy solution is to give this role directly the permission that I need but I do not want the user out of the Service Catalog do any action like stop EC2, so I want to assume **MY_SSM_ROLE** with extra permission, but I get this error

```
An error occurred (InvalidAutomationExecutionParametersException) when calling the StartAutomationExecution operation: The defined assume role is unable to be assumed.
```

base on [AWS Troubleshooting - section Assume Role Can't Be Assumed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-troubleshooting.html) either is role not existed which cannot be true for me or The assume role doesn't have a trust relationship with the Systems Manager service, now I am stuck here how should I give the trust relationship!!?

SSM Automation Document

```
description: Stop EC2 Instance
schemaVersion: '0.3'
assumeRole: '{{ AutomationAssumeRole }}'
parameters:
  AutomationAssumeRole:
    type: String
    default: 'arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNTID:role/MY_SSM_ROLE'
    description: The ARN of the role that allows Automation to perform the actions on your behalf.
  InstanceId:
    type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance::Id'
mainSteps:
  - name: StopInstance
    action: 'aws:changeInstanceState'
    inputs:
      InstanceIds:
        - '{{ InstanceId }}'
      DesiredState: stopped
```

just for a test I gave **MY_SSM_ROLE** the admin permission and also includes this policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole",
                "iam:PassRole",
                "ssm:StartAutomationExecution"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

found the solution, I had to add a proper services to **trust relationship** for **MY_SSM_ROLE** Role.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "ssm.amazonaws.com",
          "iam.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You only need trust relationship  from SSM, `ssm.amazonaws.com`